# OleDbException Microsoft Access cannot find MSysAccessStorage

Tags: entity-framework-core, jet-ef-provider

My project uses EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.OleDb v3.1 with provider in connection string Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. The code's go through several iterations including RemoveRange followed by AddRange. Currently it's this

```
boards.ForEach((board) =>
{
    if (_cutriteDbContext.Boards.Any(i => i.BoardsCode == board.BoardsCode))
    {
        _cutriteDbContext.Boards.Update(board);
    }
    else
    {
        _cutriteDbContext.Boards.Add(board);
    }
});
```

I'm getting an error that says it can't find MSysAccessStorage when it reaches the `.Boards.Any()`. Is this because the DB files are too old maybe? Has anyone encountered this?
**EDIT**: Is there a way to specify compatibility with EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.OleDb in the DbContextOptions?

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E37): The Microsoft Access
> database engine cannot find the input table or query
> 'MSysAccessStorage'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled
> correctly.    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
> hr)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
> dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
> executeResult)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
> behavior, Object& executeResult)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at
> EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.JetCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderCore(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)    at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Storage.Internal.JetExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)    at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1
> source, Expression`1 predicate)    at CutriteAPI.Repositories.CutriteRepository.<SyncBoards>b__3_1(Board board) in C:\Users\mbaker\source\repos\CutriteAPI\CutriteAPI\Repositories\CutriteRepository.cs:line 43    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)    at CutriteAPI.Repositories.CutriteRepository.SyncBoards(List`1 boards)
> in
> C:\Users\mbaker\source\repos\CutriteAPI\CutriteAPI\Repositories\CutriteRepository.cs:line
> 41    at
> CutriteAPI.Controllers.CutriteAPIController.SyncBoards(CUT_RITE_FILE
> cUT_RITE_FILE) in
> C:\Users\mbaker\source\repos\CutriteAPI\CutriteAPI\Controllers\CutriteAPIController.cs:line
> 94    at
> CutriteAPI.Controllers.CutriteAPIController.SyncLibrary(CUT_RITE_FILE
> cUT_RITE_FILE) in
> C:\Users\mbaker\source\repos\CutriteAPI\CutriteAPI\Controllers\CutriteAPIController.cs:line
> 78    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create MSysAccessStorage with a single column and a single record.
It's used for certain queries just to have one record (see Oracle DUAL table).
You can also change the name of this table (it's an ef provider for jet configuration property)

Comment: Thanks. I re-wrote it so it's using `where(condition).Count() > 0` to get past the error. There are quite a few of these DBs and I'm not supposed to be changing them since they're from a vendor. Checking your answer though. You wrote the code so I'm sure it's right.